# Cannot add property _monthsRegex, object is not extensible momentJs

Tags: react-native, momentjs, moment-timezone

my moment package version

> "moment": "^2.21.0",
>   "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23"

```
var temp = 'January 9th 2018';

console.log(moment(temp, 'MMMM Do YYYY')); // this throws error
```

I don't know how to solve it. When i run it within node project with same package version, It works. But when i run it within react native, it throws this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRgFi.png